# What is the difference between Portals, ViewContainerRef and ngComponentOutlet?

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

What is the difference between Portals, ViewContainerRef and ngComponentOutlet?
For dynamic component loading, when do we use each of these methods?

I’ve been using the method outlined in this link; https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

However I came across CDK portals which seems to use the same method and also NgComponentOutlet.

How do I decide which one to use?

Portals https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview

Answer (score 3):

Portals is the abstraction of a component resolver on an CDK level which is an external library of Angular. It takes a more UI approach as the name suggests. A portal to a component of your choice.

ViewComponentRef is literally the view of a single component which you can inject into and resolve your own components. Both the portal and ng component outlet use thus under the hood. The best thing about this is that you automatically get an instance of your component in your to edit.

NgComponentOutlet is an abstraction similar to NgTemplateOutlet which basically resolves any type you attach to it. More or less an HTML approach of the component resolver factory.

Basically, the UI directives save from you the need to compile and resolve components but have less control.